How can i pass a variable in a azure data factory pipeline to a data flow parameter
I'm creating a pipeline where I have ton of files that I have to loop through, log and load to snowflake
steps in pipeline

get metadata activity
filter for files
set variable (filename)
foreach loop
copy data step (copy file to BLOB)
data flow - where I take the file in BLOB and add filename) (please lmk if I can do this in copy data step, pretty sure I can't)

step 6 is where I'm having the issue. where do I create the parameter, in the data flow step itself. or in the source and sink data sets? I create a parameter in the data flow itself but then I don't see the parameter in the source and sink datasets to parameterize the filename that the flow writes to

Here's how you can parameterize datasets in the dataflow.
When using dataflow also, create the parameters for the datasets just like you did for copy activity.

Give these datasets as source or sink datasets for the dataflow as per your requirement. After that, in the pipeline go to Dataflow activity and you can find the dataset parameters. Here, you need to provide the values for the dataset parameters from the pipeline.

If you give parameters to the sink dataset, it will ask for that as well in this activity.
In case of all datasets source and sink of the dataflow, this is the way to provide parameters.
But in the case dataflow sink for any file system datasets like Blob or Gen2, the dataflow by default generates the part files as per given partition number. If you want to generate a single target file in every iteration dynamically, you need to use dataflow parameters here.
Leave the sink dataset as it is and don't give any parameters to it.

Give this to dataflow sink and create a string parameter in the dataflow. In the sink settings, use that parameter as file name.

Now, pass the target file name that you want to generate to this parameter from the pipeline. Pipeline expression -> @item().name

Now, if you debug the pipeline, it will loop through the files from for-each and uses it inside the dataflow.

